# Double numbers in Python using Lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to double numbers using Lambda function in python but can't understand the function that's all because I'm starting to learn python. Below is the function:

```
def myfunc(n):
  return lambda a : a * n

mydoubler = myfunc(2)

print(mydoubler(11))
```

I just need to understand how this code is working. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfunc(n): # this function is taking input n and returning a function object
  return lambda a : a * n # this function is taking input as a and we are returning this function object


mydoubler = myfunc(2) # now we are calling the returned function object if you print(mydoubler)-> this will give you function object

print(mydoubler(11)) # here we are calling the lambda function with parameters
```

If you want to implement it without lambda then you can use `partial`

```
from functools import partial
def double(n, a):
    return a * n

def my_func1(n):
    return partial(double,n)

mydoubler = my_func1(2)
print(mydoubler(11))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `myfunc` function creates and returns a closure.   In this case, it returns a function that returns its argument times `n`.  The tricky part is that `n` refers to the value in the specific call frame for `myfunc`.  In your example, `n` has the value `2`.  That instance of `n` is specific to that particular call to `myfunc`.  So if you called `myfunc` several times in a row, with several different values for `n`, each of the returned `lambda` functions would refer to a unique value of `n` unrelated to the other values.

Note that the use of `lambda` is optional.  It's just shorthand for an anonymous function.  For example, you could have written `myfunc` as:

```
def myfunc(n):
    def f(a):
        return a * n

    return f
```

which would produce the same result.

Back to the original question, here's an example of multiple closures coexisting:

```
def myfunc(n):
    def f(a):
        return a * n

    return f

mydoubler = myfunc(2)
mytripler = myfunc(3)

print(mydoubler(11))
print(mytripler(11))
```

This prints `22` followed by `33`.  This works because `mydoubler` and `mytripler` each refer to different instances of `n`.

The value of `n` can even be modified by calls to the returned closure.  For example:

```
def myfunc(n):
    def f(a):
        nonlocal n
        n += a
        return n

    return f

func = myfunc(100)

print(func(1))
print(func(5))
```

This prints `101` followed by `106`.  In this example, the `nonlocal` declaration is needed since `f` assigns to `n`.  Without it, `n` would be taken to be local to `f`.